# Date and cron with interval 10 minutes

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date

I have in my database:

```
id | text | date
1  | sdsd | 2012-01-23 08:11:00
2  | asd  | 2012-01-23 08:24:00
3  | dfdf | 2012-01-23 08:34:00
4  | fdf  | 2012-01-23 08:41:00
5  | xcvx | 2012-01-23 08:48:00
```

etc

on my server is cron with 10 minutes intervals, 
for example:

```
08:03:00
08:13:00
08:23:00
08:33:00
08:43:00
08:53:00
```

how is the best method for get this values from databases with SQL for PHP?

Comment: I don't understand what you want here - are you asking "How do I schedule cron jobs so that the schedule is based on the values in my database?"

Comment: Yeah, I'm also confused what you're trying to achieve. Could you clarify it some more?

Comment: I did not understand what has to do with the time of crons and the time you have in the database. I understand that you want to know how to get the information from the database, but for what matters the crons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return all rows that have `date` > last 10 minutes:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE `date` > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE
```

It is assumed that your table does not contain any future dates.

Answer (score 1):

Do a SQL query which looks for a time in the date field that is plus or minus 4 minutes of the current time according to PHP.

Answer (score 1):

In your cron script you could do something like this:

```
$res = mysql_query('select * from table where `date` < now()');
```

Then you simply do the thing you want to do with those rows.